# Make a negative or mould of an object with multiple components in Siemens NX

Tags: cad, siemens, siemens-nx

I have downloaded the STEP file of a welding torch from [here](https://grabcad.com/library/wp-20-tig-torch/details?folder_id=86868) on GrabCAD. I am trying to make a block in NX that would have a cavity within it in the shape of the torch. I have tried using the subtract feature but have had difficulty. I think that's due to the torch model containing multiple components.

Is anyone able to tell me how I could go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your "welding torch" model in NX a solid body or is composed of multiple sheet bodies?

Comment: @fang Thanks for your reply. It seems to be sheet bodies.

Comment: Try using "Sew" command to make them a solid body before substracting the model from the block.